# To construct a Schrödinger wave with prescribed mean position and momentum

Tags: fourier-analysis, quantum-mechanics

Let $\lambda_x, \lambda_\xi>0$ be fixed parameters which we will call *position lengthscale* and *momentum lengthscale* respectively. Fix a (position-)point $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and a (momentum-)point $\xi_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and define 
$$f(x)=\chi_{\{\lvert x-x_0\rvert <\lambda_x\}}\mathscr{F}^{-1}\left(\chi_{\{\lvert \xi-\xi_0\rvert<\lambda_{\xi}\}}\right).$$
**Question**. What can we say about the expectation values of position 
$$\langle f|x|f\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x \lvert f(x)\rvert^2\, dx$$
and of momentum
$$\langle f|p|f\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\xi \left\lvert \hat{f}(x)\right\rvert^2\, d\xi?$$
(*Optional*) What about the variances?

My guess is that the average position is $x_0$ and that the average momentum is $\xi_0$ regardless of the lenghtscales. Those will enter into the variance but I cannot predict the exact functional dependence.

Comment: I think you forget to divide by $\langle f|f\rangle$ in the expectation values.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the form of your specified functions in the first line.  But I don't know everything; maybe others will understand.  (Although, surely, $f=f(x,\xi)$, not $f(x)$.)  But if the idea is that the function is symmetric around $x_0$ and $\xi_0$, then, yes, your expectation values will be $x_0$ and $\xi_0$.  The variances will depend strongly on $\lambda_x$ and $\lambda_y$, but I don't think there is enough information to say anything further about that.

Comment: And O.L. is right, unless you are assuming that this function is already normalized.

Comment: @O.L.: &bob.sacamento: Thank you for your comments. Normalization is indeed a problem unless one assumes that $\lambda_\xi=\lambda_x^{-1}$, which moreover looks like a very natural thing to do.

Comment: @bob.sacamento: Previous comment is addressed to you too (the system doesn't let me notify two users at once).